# VB.NET Problems with Coding a Dictionary Program

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I am trying to build a dictionary program and I designed it like [this](http://www11.0zz0.com/2015/04/02/18/715798128.jpg).

I am using a txt database file with utf8 encoding which is below in the previous picture. while `\` is the separator between English and Arabic words.

when i try to translate a movie subtitle file like this:

```
1
00:00:07,376 --> 00:00:09,526
what is your name?

2
00:00:09,776 --> 00:00:12,654
jack

3
00:00:12,896 --> 00:00:15,046
nice one
```

The problem is that every subtitle file contains at least 500 line of those
and when I add it to the dictionary and press translate nothing happen as
it must identify the whole text as one word from database, all I am trying
to do is having a function like this:

http://www13.0zz0.com/2015/04/02/17/426589467.jpg

As the dictionary translate the word that found in it's database and
wrote that didn't make sense to it exactly as it is.

At last here is the code of radio button 1 that is called subtitles
and I put it under code of button `1_click` which is called translate

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("Subtitles.txt")
            Do While (True)
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
                If line Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                Dim words As String() = line.Split("\")
                Dim word As String
                For Each word In words
                    If word = TextBox1.Text Then
                        TextBox2.Text = words(+1)
                    End If
                Next
            Loop
        End Using
    End If
```

Comment: Please try to be more concise.  None of these details about dictionaries, translations, files, and subtitles have anything to do with your actual problem.  Your example code to reproduce the problem could have been reduced to a single line of code.  He [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more helpful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your check `word = TextBox1.Text`, that checks if the TextBox contains exactly the word and nothing more, if you want to replace more words you could do as follow:

```
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("Subtitles.txt")
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
    Dim translatedText As String = TextBox1.Text
    While(line IsNot Nothing)
        Dim words As String() = line.Split("\")
        Dim word As String
        For Each word In words
            If translatedText.Contains(word) Then
                translatedText = translatedText.Replace(word, words(1)) 
            End If
        Next
        line = reader.ReadLine
   End While
   TextBox2.Text = translatedText
End Using
```

I've changed a bit your cycle because that `Exit Do` is simply [ugly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming)

Comment: I suppose your dictionary contains a line that doesn't have a '\' separator. You can check if the line is correctly split changing the If translatedText.Contains(word) Then in If words.Length = 2 And translatedText.Contains(word) Then